# How to sort object by numeric keys with nesting?

Tags: javascript

I have object with numeric keys, grouped by some value, that`s why it have nesting:

```
const toSort = {
'3': {
    "key1": "test",
    "key2": "test",
},
'testVslue': {
    '1': {
        "key1": "test",
        "key2": "test",
    },
    '2': {
        "key1": "test",
        "key2": "test",
    },
},
'4': {
    "key1": "test",
    "key2": "test",
},
```

}

How can I sort the object by key growth, despite the nesting, like this:

```
const sorted = {
'testVslue': {
    '1': {
        "key1": "test",
        "key2": "test",
    },
    '2': {
        "key1": "test",
        "key2": "test",
    },
},
'3': {
    "key1": "test",
    "key2": "test",
},
'4': {
    "key1": "test",
    "key2": "test",
},
```

}

Comment: Is the nesting only one level deep?

Comment: @CKE yes, only one

Comment: what is the use since the elements of an object are directly accessible by their properties? their memory assignment can anyway be different depending on the needs of the host system

Comment: I need to visualize data by order in list

Comment: if sort alphabetically, order would be `3 4 testValue`, would that be ok?

Comment: that the problem, that I need to sort only by nested numeric keys

Answer (score 2):

https://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_oop-besides-classes.html#_traversal-order-of-properties

Own Property Keys:

Retrieves the keys of all own properties of an object, in the following order:

- First, the string keys that are integer indices (what these are is explained in the next section), in ascending numeric order.
- Then all other string keys, in the order in which they were added to the object.
- Lastly, all symbol keys, in the order in which they were added to the object.

```
console.log(toSort);
// 3 4 testValue

const sorted = {};
Object.keys(toSort).sort().forEach(function(key) {
    sorted[key] = toSort[key];
});

console.log(sorted);
// 3 4 testValue
```

so, other way is to divide it up.

```js
const sortedInteger = {};
const sortedString = {};
Object.keys(toSort).sort().forEach(function(key) {
    if (isNaN(key)) {
        sortedString[key] = toSort[key];
    }
    else {
        sortedInteger[key] = toSort[key];
    }
});

console.log(sortedString);
console.log(sortedInteger);
```

---

or how about use Map 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

```js
const sortedIntegerArray = [];
let sortedMap = new Map()

Object.keys(toSort).sort().forEach( (key) => {
    if (isNaN(key)) {
        sortedMap.set(key, toSort[key])
    }
    else {
        sortedIntegerArray.push(key);
    }
});

sortedIntegerArray.forEach( (key) => {
    sortedMap.set(key, toSort[key])
});

console.log(sortedMap)

// Map {
//     'testValue' => {
//       '1': { key1: 'test', key2: 'test' },
//       '2': { key1: 'test', key2: 'test' }
//     },
//     '3' => { key1: 'test', key2: 'test' },
//     '4' => { key1: 'test', key2: 'test' }
//   }
```